# Proper strategy in case no heap dump is generated

Tags: centos, java

I got a server running a `Java` application on `OpenJDK` and `CentOS`.

However the application seems to have a memory leak and crashes every few weeks.
The problem is that although `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` is specified no heap dump is generated.
If i create an artificial memory leak which crashes the application immediately a proper heap dump is generated.

Now i'm **not** asking for a complete solution to this problem but for a good strategy.

Is there a way to pull a heap dump on demand while the application is running after a week for example? Is there a way to figure out whats going wrong in `OpenJDK`? Do you got any alternative suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenJDK should contain a tool called `jmap` which can create a heap dump given a process id. For the exact syntax you would have to look at the [jmap man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/jmap-java-1.6.0-openjdk). If there is a memory leak then this should be visible in the heap dump even before the app crashes. I can also recommend the [eclipse memory analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) to browse the heap dump and get a list of leak suspects.

Comment: Yes that was my idea. Thanks for the info :)